# How to get this type of array format

Tags: php, php-5.6

In php i have two array like :

```
$a = ['name'=>'a','age'=>'b','city'=>'c'];
$b = ['name'=>'z','age'=>'x','city'=>'y'];

 now i want a new array like:

name=a,
age=b,
city=c,
add=arry(name=a,age=b,city=c)
```

how can i get array in this format

Comment: How does age become c and city becomes b

Comment: sorry madhur@ it was by mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either create the new array using [`array_merge()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) function. Demo: https://3v4l.org/jKGNB

```
$a = ['name'=>'a','age'=>'b','city'=>'c'];
$new_array = array_merge($a, ['add' => $a]);
```

OR,

Copy the new array as input array, and push a new key into it. Demo: https://3v4l.org/birP6

```
$a = ['name'=>'a','age'=>'b','city'=>'c'];
$new_array = $a;
$new_array['add'] = $a;
```